# Xlsxwriter Not Writing Into File

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('123.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write(3, 3, 'Test')
workbook.close()
```

I am trying to add "Test" to an excel file using xlsxwriter. But by doing so it replaces the whole excel file with only the new added text.

It's the same result when I write it into a new file.

save() for some reason doesn't even get recognized (it's white).

```
AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot `workbook.close()`, add that to the end of your program, and it should work

The syntax to close an excel file in `xlsxwriter` is very simple i.e

`workbook_object.close()`

Here workbook object is the workbook which is open and now you want to close it. Its better to save the workbook before closing it. *demo.xlsx can be any file name that  you want.*

`workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo.xlsx')`

So your final code will look like this:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('123.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write(3, 3, 'Test')
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo.xlsx')
workbook.close()
```

**EDIT:**

Based on what you provided, your problem seems to lie with the workbook not properly closing.

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()


worksheet.write(3, 3, 'hope this works :)')  # Writes a string to the file



workbook.close()
```

Comment: In short, replacing `workbook.save()` ✕ with `workbook.close()` ✓ works. There is no need to call any save function explicitly.